Задан массив ата, состоящий из натуральных чисел. Выбрать в строках самые левые наименьшие элементы и поставить их в первый столбец. Python
import random  
r = 0
print('Input first index matrix: ')
x = int(input())
print('Input second index matrix: ')
y = int(input())
array = []
for i in range(x):
    array.append([])
    for j in range(y):
        array[i].append(random.randint(0,100))
        r += 1  

массив наверное такой, а как дальше не очень понимаю

import random

print('Input number of rows: ')
x = int(input())
print('Input number of columns: ')
y = int(input())

# Создание массива и заполнение его случайными числами
array = []
for i in range(x):
    array.append([])
    for j in range(y):
        array[i].append(random.randint(0,100))

# Находим индексы наименьших элементов в каждой строке и помещаем их в первый столбец
for i in range(x):
    min_index = min(range(len(array[i])), key=array[i].__getitem__)
    # Перемещаем минимальный элемент в первый столбец
    array[i][0], array[i][min_index] = array[i][min_index], array[i][0]


print("Modified array:")
for row in array:
    print(row)

